# How to relate objects with schema.org which are on different pages?

Tags: freebase, schema.org, relate

I am searching for a solution for my problem for days and I have still no Idea if it's possible or not.

I want to relate objects/things with schema.org and microdata notation like with RDFa and the about/rel attributes.

Example:

Page 1: www.mypage.com/page1

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation" itemid="http://www.freebase.com/view/m/XYZ">
```

... some information

Page 2: www.mypage.com/page2

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation" itemid="http://www.freebase.com/view/m/0ckzqsj">
... some businessevents
```

Is there any chance to tell a validator to merge the information of those two items? As far as I know, itemref is not the right way to accomplish that ([How do I relate items in schema.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745955/how-do-i-relate-items-in-schema-org))

As far as i rememeber I read something about the @url attribute which can be used to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same itemid for both items is the correct way to say that they are both describing different properties of the same "thing". However, I don't think that search engines currently display aggregated data like this.

Comment: You where right. Search engines do not use this information at the moment (at least google and bing). But I discovered a raise in page accesses of 4,33% (compared to the records before the optimization with microdata).

Well, yes you could say this is in between the tolerance range, but the former records did not differ that much (they where pretty stable). Another point is, that the page accesses are mainly generated by direct accesses and thisfor a raise of 4,33% is not bad at all (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Schema.org has added a new sameAs property specifically for disambiguating entities in structured markup. http://schema.org/sameAs