# Can I use "inheritance" to add specific properties to nodes in json-ld with Schema.org using references?

Tags: reference, structure, schema.org, json-ld

I am struggling with using references in json-ld with schema.org.

I am trying to represent a person and a list of employments they've had at various organizations, where the person's job title is different for every organization where they've worked.

Schema.org `Person` has a property `jobTitle` and the `Organization` type has a property `employee`. I'm wanting to point the `employee` property in `Organization` to the top level same `Person` object for all the `Organization` objects using `@id`. Can I then add the specific `jobTitle` property together with the `@id`, sort of like inheritance in OO-programming? If this doesn't work, would you have suggestions for a more sensible structure?

```
"@type": "Person",
"@id": "toplevelperson",
"givenName": null,
    .
    .
    .
"worksFor": [
    {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "aaaa",
             .
             .
             . 
         "employee": {
             "@id": "toplevelperson",
             "jobTitle": "Painter"
         }
    }
```

EDIT: I attempted a solution using EmployeeRole type with property roleName similar to example 2 for OrganizationRole example 2 https://schema.org/OrganizationRole.

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Person",
"@id": "topLevelPerson",
"givenName": null,
.
.
.
"worksFor": [
    {
        "@type": "EmployeeRole",
        "worksFor" {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": null,
            .
            .
            .
            "email": null,
            "telephone": null,
            "employee": {
                "@id": "topLevelPerson"
            }
        },
        "roleName": null,
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null
    }
]
```

}

Comment: This sounds familiar to a question I answered a while ago, this might be of some help. Let me know if it's what you're looking for or not:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128187/how-do-i-relate-job-jobtitle-to-organization-worksfor-in-schema-org-markup/39433413#39433413

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using "roles" to express the same behaviour (see original post edit), which I hope links the particular jobTitle (expressed as roleName) to the particular organization. Please let me know if it doesn't look right to you! Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting approach - Having two nested "worksFor" seems odd, but it does pass validation on the structured data testing tool at least. Maybe the more important question is what your intention with JSON-LD is to begin with, if it's SEO related, it's tough to say if you'll benefit from this approach.

Comment: I'm using it for making a data model for interoperability. I wanted to make the model using standardised vocabulary and be as self-describing as possible. Not sure if this is the best approach, but it's the best I could come up with.